# How to pass the int representing the index of the swiped item to the function of the swipeActions button?

Tags: swiftui

I have a ForEach building a list and have a swipeActions running a custom function. I can get the index value of the swiped item and output it with the list, but how do you pass it into the function of the swipeActions button?
Error is on the line in the button calling the cleanUp function - "Cannot convert value of type '(UnsafePointer?, Int32) -..."

```
import SwiftUI

struct Match: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var homeTeam: String
    var id = UUID()}

var savedMatches = [
    Match(homeTeam: "discourge")]

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List{
                ForEach(Array(zip(savedMatches.indices, savedMatches)), id: \.0) { index, match in
                    Text("\(index): \(match.homeTeam)") //correctly outputs '0: discourge'
                }.swipeActions{
                    Button(role: .destructive, action: {
                        cleanUp(item: index) //when '0: discourge' is swiped, would like this to call cleanUp(item: 0)
                    },
                     label: {
                        Label("Clean Up", systemImage: "gear")
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func cleanUp (item: Int) {
   print("the item swiped has an index of \(item)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised that in my incorrect attempt the swipe worked and the function was getting executed (just passing the index was the problem). Separately, perhaps I oversimplified the example; in the real code instead of attaching to a Text(..), I'm attaching swipeActions to a list row nav link being made by a different view - should be the same, but of course, it isn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `.swipeActions{...}` to the `Text(...)`, like this:

```
struct ContentViews: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List{
                ForEach(Array(zip(savedMatches.indices, savedMatches)), id: \.0) { index, match in
                    Text("\(index): \(match.homeTeam)")
                        .swipeActions {  // <--- here
                            Button(role: .destructive, action: {
                                cleanUp(item: index) //when '0: discourge' is swiped, would like this to call cleanUp(item: 0)
                            },
                                   label: {
                                Label("Clean Up", systemImage: "gear")
                            })
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```